# Converting Rails model to SQL insert Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to convert a Rails model into an insert query?

For instance, if I have a model like:

```
m = Model.new
m.url = "url"
m.header = "header"
```

How can I get the corresponding SQL query ActiveRecord would generate if I did m.save?

I want to get: "INSERT INTO models(url, header) VALUES('url', 'header')" if possible.

Note: I don't want to actually save the model and get the query back (from log file, etc). I want to get the query IF I chose to save it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can see good reasons for getting the SQL that a SELECT would do but I don't see why you'd want the INSERT.

Comment: I want to buffer all my inserts and save the queries in a memory store, and run them all when the number of queries reaches X (run them all in a single transaction). I don't want to buffer them in Rails memory because it's not persistent.

Comment: Why not save the values you want to use somewhere and then do a bunch of `Model.new`s inside a transaction later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in Rails 3.2.13:   I think I got it right this time, it definitely does not persist to the db this time.    It also won't fire validations or callbacks so anything they change won't be in the results unless you've called them some other way.

Save this in lib as insert_sqlable.rb and you can then

```
#in your models or you can send it to ActiveRecord::Base
include InsertSqlable
```

Then it is model.insert_sql to see it.

```
#lib/insert_sqlable
module InsertSqlable
    def insert_sql
      values = arel_attributes_values
      primary_key_value = nil

      if self.class.primary_key && Hash === values
        primary_key_value = values[values.keys.find { |k|
          k.name == self.class.primary_key
        }]

        if !primary_key_value && connection.prefetch_primary_key?(self.class.table_name)
          primary_key_value = connection.next_sequence_value(self.class.sequence_name)
          values[self.class.arel_table[self.class.primary_key]] = primary_key_value
        end
      end

      im = self.class.arel_table.create_insert
      im.into self.class.arel_table

      conn = self.class.connection

      substitutes = values.sort_by { |arel_attr,_| arel_attr.name }
      binds       = substitutes.map do |arel_attr, value|
        [self.class.columns_hash[arel_attr.name], value]
      end

      substitutes.each_with_index do |tuple, i|
        tuple[1] = conn.substitute_at(binds[i][0], i)
      end

      if values.empty? # empty insert
        im.values = Arel.sql(self.class.connectionconnection.empty_insert_statement_value)
      else
        im.insert substitutes
      end

      conn.to_sql(im,binds)
    end
end
```

It turns out the code is in ActiveRecord::Relation and not ActiveRecord::Persistence.   The only significant change is the last line which generates the sql instead of performing it.

Comment: For me, this also seems to run the actual query.

Comment: Yes, it was completely wrong before.   There isn't a quick way to do it, but you can reproduce how Rails uses Arel and the database connection layer to generate the query.

Answer (score 10):

On Rails 4.1, I found the below code snippet working:

```
record = Post.new(:title => 'Yay', :body => 'This is some insert SQL')

record.class.arel_table.create_insert
  .tap { |im| im.insert(record.send(
            :arel_attributes_with_values_for_create,
            record.attribute_names)) }
  .to_sql
```

Thanks to https://coderwall.com/p/obrxhq/how-to-generate-activerecord-insert-sql

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to save the model you call m.destroy when you are done with the object.

You can log the sql query by debugging it like this

Rails.logger.debug "INSERT INTO models(url, header) VALUES(#{m.url}, #{m.header}).inspect

Comment: I don't wish to make any database calls at all.

Comment: Then i think you would need to build a query from the params and keep it in a variable in case you want to execute it later. If you save the query as a string in case you want to save it later you can call ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(string_created)

Answer (score 0):

After search a lot over the Internet and forums, I think I found a better solution for your problem: **just requires two line of code**.

I found a good gem that do exactly what you want, but this gem only works for Rails 3.2 and older. I [talked with author](https://github.com/vivrass/models-to-sql/issues/1) and he doesn't want support this gem anymore. So I discovered by myself how to support Rails 4.0 and now I'm maintaining this gem.

#### Download the ["models-to-sql-rails" gem here](https://github.com/paladini/models-to-sql-rails), supporting Rails 4.0 and older.

---

With this gem, you can easily do the following. (the examples inside *values* are just a joke, you will get the correct values when using it in your object).

For objects:

```
object.to_sql_insert
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('Wow, amaze gem', 'much doge')
```

For array of objets:

```
array_of_objects.to_sql_insert
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('Awesome doge', "im fucking cop")
# INSERT INTO modelName (field1, field2) VALUES ('much profit', 'much doge')
# (...)
```

Just see the [Github of this project](https://github.com/paladini/models-to-sql-rails) and you'll find how to install and use this wonderful gem.